# Using Django url regex for nested routes

Tags: django

Hi excited to move from rails to django but having trouble.

The following has my urls and corresponding view's action.  When both urls enabled, PublisherDomain breaks the PublishersSingle(page is visitable but not rendering content.  However when PublisherDomain code is commented out, PublishersSingle works and renders the right content.  My question is: Whats wrong that is causing this over ride and break?  I pasted the elements where I believe theres something wrong.

Urls.py

```
url(r'^publishers/(?P<domain>.*)/$', 'firm.views.PublisherDomain'),
url(r'^publishers/(?P<domain>.*)/(?P<period>.*)/$', 'firm.views.PublishersSingle'),
```

Views.py

```
def PublisherDomain(request, domain):
   return render_to_response()

def PublisherSingle(request, domain, period):
   return render_to_response.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your regex. In your matching group `(?P<domain>.*)`, `.*` matches 0 or more of *any* character, including forward slashes. This means that your first URL pattern matches `/publishers/domain/period/`, so the request is handled by your PublisherDomain view instead of PublisherSingle.

A more common regex would be `(?P<domain>[\w-]+)`, which would match one or more uppercase letters A-Z, lowercase a-z, digits 0-9, hyphen or underscore.

As an aside, Please consider following the python convention and naming your view functions `publisher_domain` and `publisher_single`. To a python programmer, the name `PublisherDomain` looks like a class, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code I used if people are looking for a specific example

```
publishers/(?P<domain>[\w-]+)/(?P<period>[\w-]+)/$
```